# codeigniter: The value from the last text field repeats itself or doesn't get the value from the text field

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I select 2 text fields and input 'alpha' on the first text field and second on the 'beta'. When I display it on the next page It only shows the second value which is 'beta'. What is the problem with my code? I already foreach the the variable that holds the data.

This is the view for form. (jscript)

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {  

        $('#bookinfo_adult').change(function(){

            var num = $('#bookinfo_adult').val();                  

            var i = 0; 
            var html = ''; 

            for (i=1;i<=num;i++) {

                html += 'Adult ' + i + ': <input type="text" name="passenger-' + i + '"/><br/>'; 
            }


            $('#List').html(html);
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

This is the form

```
      Adult:      
    <select id="bookinfo_adult" name="bookinfo_adult">
    <option value="0">- SELECT -</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
    <div id="List"></div>
```

This is controller

```
for ($i=1;$i<=$data['num'];$i++) {
                //concatinate number of fields to a variable
                $name=array();
                $name=$this->input->post('passenger-'.$i);
                $value=array();
                $value='val'.$i;
                $data['bookinfo_passengers']=array();
                $data['bookinfo_passengers']=array($value=>$name);
            }
```

This is whats on my display view

```
     for($a=1;$a<=$num;$a++){
    foreach($bookinfo_passengers as $value=>$name)
    {
        echo $value.'='.$name;
    }     
            }
```

Comment: where do you think is the problem?

Comment: What is the exact output you get from the view? Analyzing your view, normally the output should be "val1=alpha val2=beta" (without the extra space). What are you getting?

Comment: Hi sir, I'm getting val2=betaval2=beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are restarting the array every loop and you are overriding the old data with the new one:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=$data['num'];$i++) {
            //concatinate number of fields to a variable
            $name=array();
            $name=$this->input->post('passenger-'.$i);
            $value=array();
            $value='val'.$i;
            $data['bookinfo_passengers']=array(); ---> **put this outside of the loop**
            $data['bookinfo_passengers']=array($value=>$name); ---> this will override the previous data.
        }
```

try this:

```
 $data['bookinfo_passengers']=array();
 $tmp = array();
 for ($i=1;$i<=$data['num'];$i++) {
            //concatinate number of fields to a variable
            $name=array();
            $name=$this->input->post('passenger-'.$i);
            $value=array();
            $value='val'.$i;
            $tmp[$value] = $name;
        }

 $data['bookinfo_passengers']=$tmp;
```

Then use it like:

```
foreach($data['bookinfo_passengers'] as $value=>$name)
    {
        echo $value.'='.$name;
    }
```

Comment: That has been bugging me for many hours now. Thank you for telling and explaining :)